# System.out.println - println is not correctly spelled in Eclipse IDE

Tags: java, eclipse

I just started using the Eclipse IDE and for a first test I created a file and entered the following:

```
class Vehicle {
   public Vehicle(String s) {
      System.out.println("X");
   }
   // public Vehicle() { }  
}
public class Car extends Vehicle {
   public Car(String s) {
      System.out.println("Y");
   }
   public static void main(String [] args) {
      new Car("Z");
   }
}
```

But I immediately get errors saying println is not correctly spelled. Can someone tell me if there's something I am missing?

Comment: @tabchas The error is not programmatic; it is denoted by the zigzag line under the println.

Comment: Something is obviously not configured correctly.  Is code completion working?

Comment: Thanks Vulcan. That's correct.

Comment: Code completion is not working. I just downloaded the latest version of Eclipse. Started it up, created a test file and entered my code.

Comment: Did you create a text file or a Java file? A simple text editor will underline println, since it's not a word.

Comment: @Evan - thanks. yes this was my problem. can you create this as an answer so I can accept it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you have created an `txt` file instead of a `JAVA` file .

Because of this it is not able to recognize keywords related to java, thereby giving error that the word is not correctly spelled.
If you will change `println` to `print` ,it will stop giving error .As Print is a proper word in English.
But here you need to change extension of file from `.txt` to `.java`

Answer (score 0):

In Eclipse click on File Menu -> New -> Class
Give Class name as Car and Click on Finish button.
It will create Car.java file.
Then in Car.java file write below code

```
class Vehicle { 
   public Vehicle(String s) { 
      System.out.println("X"); 
   } 
    public Vehicle() { }  
  }
 public class Car extends Vehicle {  
  public Car(String s) {    
   System.out.println("Y");   
 }   
 public static void main(String [] args) { 
      new Car("Z"); 
   } 
}
```

In the Vehicle class defult constructor is required as Class Car extending Vehicle class.Otherwise it will show error as 'Implicit super constructor Vehicle() is undefined. Must explicitly invoke another constructor' for constuctor of Car class.
Now just run the file s Java Application. It will show output as Y on console.

Answer (score -1):

I just received this error and the fix was to restart Eclipse. This error seems very random.